# How to complete order after successful payment opencart api android?

Tags: android, opencart, checkout, orders, payumoney

I am developing an android app using Opencart API.

I could managed to get payumoney payment responses and could verify them. But I don't understand what's next. The order status has to be updated, History to be created and the cart has to be cleared.

I guess `checkout/success` is meant for web and it returns html. I just need the order status updated and cart cleared.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking in the wrong place.
Each stop payment has its controller to receive a response about the status of payment. Usually it lies in the **controller/payment** .

The payment system after payment calls this method and the entire procedure for creating and changing the status occurs in it. 
Usually it simply calls the method

```
  $this->model->checkout->order->addHistory(...);
```

Comment: No explanation at all on the parameters and what it does?